# Como criar uma tela de validação embutida?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Desculpem-me se o titulo não está tão explicativo, mas a dúvida é a seguinte: tenho que fazer um CRUD e já consegui fazer o C e o R, mas estou fazendo a página de *Update* agora e o esquema é mais ou menos assim:

Tem uma página `Index` listando os objetos que podem sofrer alterações:

[image: Exemplo]

e o que eu gostaria é que, quando eu clicasse em um dos links, fosse exibido apenas um modal com os campos que eu posso editar, sendo que o link de edição contém 2 campos com valores `checkbox` (`true` ou `false`) e o link de inativação é basicamente a execução de uma *query update* em sql.

Como poderia fazer isso?

Obrigado, se precisarem de mais informações, me avisem!

Comment: Bem vindo ao [pt.so]. Sua pergunta está um pouco ampla. Poderia postar o código que está utilizando e explicar um pouco mais o que deseja. Aproveitando, veja o [ask] e o faça um [tour], para aprender um pouco mais sobre o funcionamento do site para assim aumentar suas chances de conseguir uma boa resposta.

Answer (score 0):

bom você pode recuperar pela a url ficaria mais ou menos assim,

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Editar">
   <ItemStyle Width="6%" />
   <HeaderTemplate>Editar
   </HeaderTemplate>
   <ItemTemplate>
       <asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="HyperLink1" NavigateUrl='<%# String.Format("~/Pages/Editar.aspx?{0}", Eval("Id")) %>'Text="Editar"> </asp:HyperLink>
 </ItemTemplate>
```

e em seu código c# da pagina de editar você pode recuperar o id usando Request.QueryString.ToString()

Answer (score 0):

[Usando Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals) para a atualização de dados, você pode construir seu formulário com modal. O envio de informações pode ser feito através de [Ajax usando jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/), por exemplo. É importante dizer que é preciso tratar a tela para exibir uma mensagem de falha para o usuário quando uma falha ocorre.

Para a inativação, você também pode usar Ajax, exibindo uma mensagem apropriada para o usuário em caso de sucesso ou falha.

Temos vários exemplos aqui no site sobre como fazer isso. [Aqui achei um exemplo funcional](https://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/0fscmf3L/).